# Log4j unable to include project build directory in Local classpath in maven War project

Tags: java, maven, log4j, m2eclipse, maven-war-plugin

I am trying to build a Maven EAR project that has a WAR project as a module. When I try to add log4j to it, it is unable to find the log4j.properties file which is located in the src/main/java folder of the web project.

It gives the error below -

```
[6/12/15 12:43:26:786 IST] 0000009c SystemOut     O log4j: Trying to find [log4j.properties] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
[6/12/15 12:43:26:786 IST] 0000009c SystemOut     O log4j: Could not find resource: [null].
```

Below is my pom.xml file from the web project

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>HR-PrepLoad-ui</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>${project.artifactId}</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.hemant.css.hr</groupId>
            <artifactId>HR-PrepLoad</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.hemant.css.hr</groupId>
            <artifactId>HR-PrepLoad-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.hemant.css.hr</groupId>
        <artifactId>HR-PrepLoad</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>
</project>
```

Does anybody have any suggestions of what might be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

your `log4j.properties` file should be in resource folder.

Try putting it from `src/main/java` to resource folder

Comment: I first tried that but as it wasn't working as required I place my property file in src/main/java and still unable to get my logging work

Comment: it is in the "resources" folder, not "resource"